# How to detect when an agent has picked up the phone on B party after going through Queue on B party in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

I am working on a development project in Asterisk where I call B party via auto-dialer. When call is answered at B party, call goes to their queue and an announcement is played. Their agents pickup the call in between their announcement. I have to transfer the call to another extension when their agent picks up. I have tried WaitForSilence but their agents don't even stop for 1 second and if there is no one on the other side, they hangup. I have also tweaked in AMD but there is no success. How can I detect when their agent picks up the call?

**EDIT:**

I am using Asterisk 11.

Comment: Where is programming question here? What you are asking in general case seams like can be "detected" only by strong AI.

Comment: This is regarding to the call events. I wanted to know if there is any event or method which can be used to detect this.

Comment: Detect what? If you control app which do queue, sure you have events, see queue_log. If queue on remote host - first you need analize sound, convert to text, UNDERSTAND text. Most close is IBM Watson, but will be very costly and low accuracy for your request. Anyway, it will require knowledge you not demonostrated in question.

Comment: Using any Speech-to-Text API will cost a lot. There is no event being generated in case of remote agent picking up the call. That is why I posted it here if anyone has any kind of code/mechanism/script related to this. I have to detect when a remote agent picks up the call.

Comment: I know some humans in callcenter who can't solve this task.. No, you can't without voice understanding/Strong AI.

Comment: If 60% success is okay, you can wait for 4 sec silence.

Comment: Actually remote agents don't even wait for 1 second and they disconnect the call within 3-4 seconds if there is no response from calling party.

Comment: This is not site where you can find free worker for your job. If you have question, please ask.